# Collisions between sprites in SpriteKit

Tags: physics, ios, spritekit, xcode, swift

I'm making a game in XCode using SpriteKit. The game has a player and different types of projectiles that he has to avoid. When the player collides with the projectiles, the score changes and the projectile disappears. However, when two projectiles collide, they kind of bounce away.
I want to make that every time two projectiles collide, they act like nothing happened and they keep going in their original path. What should I do?

*Note: This is not the whole code, it's just what matters.

```
    import SpriteKit

    struct Physics {
        static let player : UInt32 = 1
        static let missileOne : UInt32 = 2
        static let missileTwo : UInt32 = 3
    }

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "p1.png")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        player.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/5)
        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: player.size)
        player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        player.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Physics.player
        player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = Physics.missileOne
        player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = Physics.missileTwo

        var missileOneTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnMissileOne"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        var missileTwoTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.2, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnMissileTwo"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        self.addChild(player)
    }

    //When contact happens
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
    var secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == Physics.player) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == Physics.missileOne)) {

        CollisionWithMissileOne(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, missileOne: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)

    } else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == Physics.player) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == Physics.missileTwo)){

        CollisionWithMissileTwo(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, missileTwo: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)

    } else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == Physics.missileOne)&&(secondBody.categoryBitMask == Physics.missileTwo)) {

        CollisionBetweenMissiles(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, missileTwo: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)

        } 

    }

//For Player and MissileOne
    func CollisionWithMissileOne(player: SKSpriteNode, missileOne: SKSpriteNode) {

        missileOne.removeFromParent()
    }

//For Player and MissileTwo
    func CollisionWithMissileOne(player: SKSpriteNode, missileTwo: SKSpriteNode) {

        missileTwo.removeFromParent()
    }

//For MissileOne and MissileTwo
        func CollisionBetweenMissiles(missileOne: SKSpriteNode, missileTwo: SKSpriteNode) {

        ???WHAT SHOULD I CODE HERE???

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to modify the [`collisionBitMask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/collisionBitMask) property of your SKPhysicsBodies.
You can set a bitmask to make collision rules. Objects that shares a same bit collides together. Since `collisionBitMask` is a `UInt32`, you can set up to 32 different layers of collision.

Set your projectiles in different layers depending on who launched the projectile.

[Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30560021/1392046) you'll probably be interested in.